# Nested handlebars partials

Tags: handlebars.js, partial-views, partial

I am trying to render out the following partials

```
<div class="section></div> //partial section
```

```
<div class="title">I am the title</div> //partial title
```

```
<div class="summary">I am the summary</div> //partial title
```

```
{{#>section}}
  {{>title}}
  {{>summary}}
{{/section}}
```

I want the section to wrap both the title and the summary. Is this possible?